# Border of a Frame is not shown

Tags: qt, pyqt

This is the relevant code of the frame

```
self.frame = QtWidgets.QFrame(self)
self.frame.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.Box)
self.frame.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 710, 381, 121))              
self.frame.setLineWidth(2)
self.frame.setMidLineWidth(0)
self.frame.setStyleSheet("border-color:white")
self.frame.setObjectName("frame")
```

Problem is that the border of the frame is not shown in the window

Answer (score 0):

You should add it in one **layout** like `QVBoxLayout`, **You created a frame but never add it to any layout, so it doesn't show.**

```
import sys
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QWidget,QFrame,QVBoxLayout
from PySide6 import QtGui
from PySide6 import QtCore


class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setWindowTitle("My App")
        self.setGeometry(0,0,600,400)

        self.frame = QFrame(self)
        self.frame.setFrameShape(QFrame.Box)
        self.frame.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 710, 381, 121))
        self.frame.setLineWidth(2)
        self.frame.setMidLineWidth(0)
        self.frame.setStyleSheet("border-color:white")
        self.frame.setObjectName("frame")

        layout=QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.frame)
        self.setLayout(layout)


app = QApplication(sys.argv)

window = Window()
window.show()

app.exec()
```

**output:**

[image]

you can also use `self.setCentralWidget(self.frame)` if you use QMainwindow.

Comment: This has nothing to do with layouts. In fact: 1. the border is black, not white; 2. if you remove the lines related to the layout and just increase the size of the widget (or use a smaller value for the top of the geometry), the child frame is properly shown at the specified coordinates. The problem was that the stylesheet was insufficient.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the border color is insufficient, as you need to specify all border properties: width, style and color.

You should also always use [selectors](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-syntax.html#selector-types) for widgets that can be containers.

The correct stylesheet would be:

```
    QFrame#frame { 
        border: 2px solid white; 
    }
```

<sup>Note: you should always use [layout managers](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html), even [in Designer](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/designer-layouts.html).</sup>